# How does Haskell scrap the boilerplate?

Tags: haskell

I am trying to wrap my head around this article:

http://www.haskell.org/haskellwiki/Scrap_your_boilerplate

Even though I know what fmap is and what a functor is (thanks to ["Learn you a haskell for great good"](http://learnyouahaskell.com/)), I am unable to understand this article. Can somebody explain to me in simple terms how Haskell scraps the boilerplate?

Comment: SYB and other generics libraries are mostly useful when you've been designing DSLs, specifically when you have recursive `data` declarations with multiple constructors.  E.g. `data Language a = Statement (Language a) | Expr (Language a) | Var a | BinOp String (Language a) (Language a)`.  If you don't write code like that, don't worry about SYB yet.  If you want to know just to learn, try implementing a small language first, then read the SYB paper.  Also I've found Uniplate easier to understand than Syb.

Comment: @John L, I was thinking that 'scrap your boilerplate' is a generic idea involving higher-order functions and generics and I can understand it if somebody explains these examples on Haskell Wiki. But looks like it's quite difficult to understand.

Comment: rather than difficult to understand, I'd say that it's a technique to solve a specific set of problems in a certain domain.  If you haven't been working in the problem domain, it's not clear what SYB offers or why it's helpful.  You could try the "Scrap Your Zippers" paper, which is a specific case of using generics.  https://www.cs.indiana.edu/~adamsmd/papers/scrap_your_zippers/

Answer (score 5):

If you're new to haskell, you probably shouldn't worry at all about SYB. It's not something fundamental or even commonly used (I've never used it myself).

SYB is a library package for Haskell, not part of Haskell itself or even one of the base libraries. See here: http://www.cs.uu.nl/wiki/GenericProgramming/SYB

You may want to read through (the last paper in) http://research.microsoft.com/en-us/um/people/simonpj/papers/hmap/

Comment: thanks for the links. I hope I can understand Simon PJ's paper.

Answer (score 4):

http://foswiki.cs.uu.nl/foswiki/GenericProgramming/SYB may be a better resource to read about SYB (a few of the links are broken because some things on `haskell.org` have changed urls, but the rest work).

To generally answer your question, here's a quote from the main page:

> ### Datatype-generic programming
>
> Datatype-generic programming consists of defining functions on the structure of datatypes, rather than on a datatype itself. In this way, one can define functions that work for many different datatypes.
>
> In SYB, the structure of datatypes is not directly exposed to the programmer. Instead, generic combinators are used to define the generic functions. These combinators are implemented using fundamental functions from the Data and Typeable classes.

Comment: can you give some examples of datatype-generic programming and how it cuts the boilerplate?

Comment: It "cuts the boilerplate" in the way that you can write one function that works on X datatypes, instead of X functions, each one doing the same thing for an individual data type. As a *very* generalized example, say you (for some reason) decided to implement a Linked List in haskell - you could write a generic function using something like SYB that could still sort both that and normal Haskell lists, returning the proper type (if you sorted your "linked list", it'd return a similar "linked list", if you sorted a regular list, it'd return a regular list).

Comment: Understood advantages of generic programming. Could you also help me understand the examples in the Haskell Wiki?

Comment: @Amber: that linked list example is rather poor.  Ordinary type classes suffice for that.

Comment: @John L, yeah, honestly, I simply wasn't very inspired example-wise at the time. I don't happen to use SYB-type stuff enough to have a good example on hand. (Though just relying on type classes wouldn't work out as well if the linked listed had a different access mechanism for a given element compared to standard haskell lists.)