# How can I remove all the boilerplate introduced by Trees That Grow?

Tags: haskell, boilerplate

I'm trying to define a programming language in Haskell. I wish to make the AST extensible: users of the AST module (for instance a pretty printer, an interpreter, a compiler, a type system, a language server and so on) should be able to extend it, by adding both new functionalities and new data (new datatypes to extend the syntax as well as new fields to the current data constructors to store data needed by the various components).

I tried to achieve this goal by using [Trees That Grow](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/research/uploads/prod/2016/11/trees-that-grow.pdf) (TTG). It works, but it results in way too much boilerplate. My minimal prototype becomes 10 times larger in terms of lines of code, and this number grows by the AST size times the number of extensions. Changing something minor requires changing several lines of the AST module, while changing something in the way extensibility is implemented would require rewriting most of it.

Is there any way to reduce the amount of boilerplate needed, or ideally remove it altogether?

#### Example with code of what I have so far

##### The "base" AST

This is just one small piece of the AST. It's something very similar to JSON, as I decided to start with a small prototype.

```hs
module AST ( KeyValue(..), Data(..) ) where

data KeyValue = KV String Data deriving (Show, Eq, Ord)

data Data =
    Null |
    Int Int |
    Num Double |
    Bool Bool |
    String String |
    Array [Data] |
    Object [KeyValue] deriving (Show, Eq, Ord)
```

##### The extensible AST, via Trees That Grow

In order to extend it via TTG, the datatypes become something like this:

```hs
data KeyValueX x =
    KVX (XKV x) String (DataX x) |
    KeyValueX (XKeyValue x)
 
data DataX x =
    NullX (XNull x) |
    IntX (XInt x) Int |
    NumX (XNum x) Double |
    BoolX (XBool x) Bool |
    StringX (XString x) String |
    ArrayX (XArray x) [DataX x] |
    ObjectX (XObject x) [KeyValueX x] |
    DataX (XData x)
```

Each of those types with a name starting in `X` is a `type family`:

```hs
type family XKV x
type family XKeyValue x
type family XNull x
type family XInt x
type family XNum x
type family XBool x
type family XString x
type family XArray x
type family XObject x
type family XData x
```

Further each of them requires to be listed in a type that makes it easier to derive classes:

```hs
type ForallX (c :: Type -> Constraint) x = (
    c (XKV x), c (XKeyValue x),
    c (XNull x), c (XInt x), c (XNum x), c (XBool x),
    c (XString x), c (XArray x), c (XObject x), c (XData x)
    )

-- now we can do:
deriving instance ForallX Show x => Show (KeyValueX x)
deriving instance ForallX Show x => Show (DataX x)
deriving instance ForallX Eq x => Eq (KeyValueX x)
deriving instance ForallX Eq x => Eq (DataX x)
deriving instance ForallX Ord x => Ord (KeyValueX x)
deriving instance ForallX Ord x => Ord (DataX x)
```

And of course everything requires to be exported:

```hs
module AST ( KeyValueX(..), DataX(..),
             XKV, XKeyValue,
             XNull, XNum, XBool, XString, XArray, XObject, XData,
             ForallX
           ) where
```

##### An extension to the AST

This is what is needed in order to create an extension. Even just the "identity" extension (UnDecorated) which needs to be provided.

For every instance you need to implement a typeclass for the type family of every type and data constructor:

```hs
data UD  -- UnDecorated, identity extension
 
type instance XKV UD = ()
type instance XKeyValue UD = Void
 
type instance XData UD = Void
type instance XNull UD = ()
type instance XInt UD = ()
type instance XNum UD = ()
type instance XBool UD = ()
type instance XString UD = ()
type instance XArray UD = ()
type instance XObject UD = ()
```

Then, in order to do things properly and ergonomic enough for the user, you need patterns and type aliases for every data constructor and data type:

```hs
type KeyValue = KeyValueX UD
pattern KV :: String -> Data -> KeyValue
pattern KV x y <- KVX _ x y where KV x y = KVX () x y
 
type Data = DataX UD
pattern Null :: Data
pattern Null <- NullX _ where Null = NullX ()
pattern DInt :: Int -> Data
pattern DInt x <- IntX _ x where DInt x = IntX () x
pattern DNum :: Double -> Data
pattern DNum x <- NumX _ x where DNum x = NumX () x
pattern DBool :: Bool -> Data
pattern DBool x <- BoolX _ x where DBool x = BoolX () x
pattern DString :: String -> Data
pattern DString x <- StringX _ x where DString x = StringX () x
pattern Array :: [Data] -> Data
pattern Array x <- ArrayX _ x where Array x = ArrayX () x
pattern Object :: [KeyValue] -> Data
pattern Object x <- ObjectX _ x where Object x = ObjectX () x
```

And of course all this stuff should be exported too:

```hs
module AST ( ...,
              UD,
              KeyValue, Data,
              pattern KV,
              pattern Null, pattern Num, pattern Bool,
              pattern String, pattern Array, pattern Object
           ) where
```

##### Summary

TTG turned my simple 10-line module, into a module of more than 100 lines where 90% of the code is boring, hard-to-maintain boilerplate:

- The original (unextensible) AST module took around 10 lines.
- The AST for the extensible version ended up taking about 50 lines and each of the data constructors (including their related type families) is mentioned around 4 times.

  - On top of that, every AST extension (including the required "identity" one) takes another 50 lines and mentions each of the data constructor another 3 times.

I would estimate that the whole language could take a couple dozen types with a total of more than a hundred of data constructors. Then I would need to define a handful of extensions to the AST. A non-extensible AST would take around 100 lines (as an order of magnitude), while one extended via TTG would take around 10,000. All the required boilerplate would make all of this unmanageable for me.

#### Question

Is there any way to reduce the amount of boilerplate needed, or ideally remove it altogether?

Otherwise are there any alternative ways to make my AST extensible without requiring this much work?

Comment: Could this help?  https://stackoverflow.com/q/7383162

Comment: @RobertHarvey: that stackoverflow question doesn't seem to have any information directly useful to my problem, no. It's possible that the SYB library may be of help, but I have no experience with it and wouldn't have any idea on how to use it to help me solve this problem.

Comment: If you want something simple, just use GADTs (when the index type is closed) or data families (when it’s open). The error messages are _way_ easier to understand than with type families, and it’s more incremental—you can choose exactly where you want to bother with indexing, and how fine-grained your index types are, to avoid rewriting parts of the tree that don’t need to change; and it extends naturally to techniques like typed typechecking. At the other extreme, the nuclear-magic option is [hypertypes](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/hypertypes).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can merge all of the type families into one indexed by a symbol:

```
data KeyValueX x =
    KVX (X "KVX" x) String (DataX x) |
    KeyValueX (X "KeyValueX" x)
  deriving Generic
 
data DataX x =
    NullX (X "NullX" x) |
    IntX (X "IntX" x) Int |
    NumX (X "NumX" x) Double |
    BoolX (X "BoolX" x) Bool |
    StringX (X "StringX" x) String |
    ArrayX (X "ArrayX" x) [DataX x] |
    ObjectX (X "ObjectX" x) [KeyValueX x] |
    DataX (X "DataX" x)
  deriving Generic

--

type family X (s :: k) (x :: l) :: Type
```

Use generics to grab all of the constructor names:

```
type ForAllX c x = (AllX c (CNames (DataX x)) x, AllX c (CNames (KeyValueX x)) x)

deriving instance ForAllX Eq x => Eq (DataX x)
deriving instance ForAllX Eq x => Eq (KeyValueX x)

-- CNames defined using generics, below
```

All of the boilerplate up to that point could also be generated from the "base AST" using Template Haskell.

Having only one type family makes it easy to define extensions with catch-all clauses:

```
data UD

type instance X s UD = XUD s

type family XUD (s :: Symbol) :: Type where
  XUD "KeyValueX" = Void
  XUD "DataX" = Void
  XUD _ = ()
```

As for the patterns, maybe just exposing the constructors is not so bad? GHC does that.

Imports and generics code to make this answer self-contained:

```
{-# LANGUAGE
  DataKinds,
  DeriveGeneric,
  PolyKinds,
  StandaloneDeriving,
  TypeFamilies,
  UndecidableInstances #-}
module T where

import Data.Kind (Constraint, Type)
import Data.Void
import GHC.Generics
import GHC.TypeLits

type CNames a = GCNames (Rep a)

type family GCNames (f :: Type -> Type) :: [Symbol] where
  GCNames (M1 D c f) = GCNames f
  GCNames (f :+: g) = GCNames f ++ GCNames g
  GCNames (M1 C (MetaCons name _ _) f) = '[name]

type family (xs :: [k]) ++ (ys :: [k]) :: [k] where
  '[] ++ ys = ys
  (x ': xs) ++ ys = x ': (xs ++ ys)

type family AllX (c :: Type -> Constraint) (xs :: [Symbol]) (x :: l) :: Constraint where
  AllX c '[] x = ()
  AllX c (s ': ss) x = (c (X s x), AllX c ss x)
```

Gist: https://gist.github.com/Lysxia/3f6781b3a307a7e0c564920d6277bee2

Comment: Neat! I'm surprised of how much boilerplate you managed to get rid of.